# How to set dynamic mapping between two models in django

Tags: python, django

I have two models "milestone" and "project", the code as below:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ID = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField('Project Name', max_length=100)
    ShortName = models.CharField('Project Short Name', max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name

class Milestone(models.Model):
Project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Name
```

When i create a milestone, i can select a project and then the milestone belongs to that project, for example, `project1---> m1;  project2 --->m2`
Then in an other model "Task", i want to create a task belong to a special project and milestone. The code is as below:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200)  
    Project = models.ForeignKey(Project,null=True, blank=True)
    Milestone = models.ForeignKey(Milestone,null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name
```

The problem is that when i create a Task and select a project, then the itemlist of the milestone field is always including two "m1" and "m2", i want that when i select project1 the list only show m1, and when i select project2 the list only show m2.

How can i implement this? Thanks

**Updated**
My folder structure

```
 mysite_new/

      manage.py
      mysite/
      ------ __init__.py
             urls.py
             setting.py
             wsgi.py
             templates/
                      default.html

      ticket/
      ------__init__.py
            models.py
            view.py
            urls.py
            admin.py
            js/
              ---- project_change.js
```

in admin.py

```
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
          js = ['js/project_change.js',]
admin.site.register(Task,TaskAdmin)
```

In urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/login', MyView().login),

    url(r'^hello/', hello),
    (r'^product_change/','project_choices'),


)
```

And in my db
   [image]
In the add task web site:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ticket/task/add/`
[image]

I don't change any of your code, could you please help to check what is the wrong with my code ?

**Update**
Thanks very much. Arulmurugan, a kind-hearted man

Comment: I think there is a flawed assumption here - would you not want to have the `milestone.project`, and `task.project` the same?

Comment: I want if i select task.project and the task.milestone will be the project's milestone, not all milestones

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this in the admin site or your custom view?

Comment: @Raunak Agarwal in the admin site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve this using jQuery and Ajax. Try using the following:

#### project_change.js

```
(function($){   
    $(function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#id_Project').bind('change', project_change);            
            $('#id_Milestone > option').show();
            if ($('#id_Project').val() != '') {
                var project_id = $('#id_Project').val();
                $.ajax({
                "type"      : "GET",
              "url"         : "/product_change/?project_id="+project_id,
                "dataType"  : "json",
              "cache"       : false,
                "success"   : function(json) {
                    $('#id_Milestone >option').remove();
                    for(var j = 0; j < json.length; j++){
                        $('#id_Milestone').append($('<option></option>').val(json[j][0]).html(json[j][1]));
                    }
                }           
            });
            }
        });
    });  
})(django.jQuery);

// based on the project, milestone will be loaded

var $ = django.jQuery.noConflict();

function project_change()
{
    var project_id = $('#id_Project').val();
    $.ajax({
    "type"      : "GET",
  "url"         : "/product_change/?project_id="+project_id,
    "dataType"  : "json",
  "cache"       : false,
    "success"   : function(json) {
        $('#id_Milestone > option').remove();
        for(var j = 0; j < json.length; j++){
            $('#id_Milestone').append($('<option></option>').val(json[j][0]).html(json[j][1]));
        }
    }           
})(jQuery);
}
```

Include the following in **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson

from ticket.models import Milestone

def project_choices(request): 
    milestone_list = []
    project_id = request.GET.get('project_id')
    milestones = Milestone.objects.filter(project = project_id)    
    [milestone_list.append((each_milestone.pk,each_milestone.name)) for each_milestone in milestones]
    json = simplejson.dumps(milestone_list)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

In **urls.py**:

```
from ticket.views import project_choices

urlpatterns = patterns(
    (r'^product_change/', project_choices),
)
```

In **admin.py** where you want to load milestone based on project:

```
class Media:
    js = ['/path/to/project_change.js',]
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in the urls.py, How to use the product_change, should i  put the class Media in the ModelAdmin class?

Comment: Yes. You need to add `class Media` in ModelAdmin class.

Comment: You just need need to include the url pointing to the `project_choices` function. I have defined a change event and it will load the milestone based using ajax.

Comment: How can i use the product_change, should i browse it by http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_change/ ?  I put your code in my project, but it does not work, i want it will effect the project change form of my admin site, it is not my custom site

Comment: This is for admin site only. Not for custom site. You don't need to browse to the url. It will be called automatically, when project is changed. Add the url to your project's main `urls.py`. Make sure that the view is referred without mistakes. Add `class Media` to admin class of `Task` model.

Comment: Hi arulmr, i have update my question,please have a check. By the way, thanks for your help, this confused me so long, i indeed wish you can help me to resolve this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20937/discussion-between-arulmr-and-jimwan)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [django dynamic choices](https://github.com/charettes/django-dynamic-choices) for this

It implements something similar to arulmr's answer but in a generic way where you can set up the mappings in django code.  There isn't any documentation but the project has good unit tests and is written by a django core developer.